# Does Batch Apex fire off triggers?

Tags: trigger, batch, apex

For example, If I have a bunch triggers that aren't bulkified, so I'll end up hitting the governing limits were to do 100 insert opportunities in an separate apex class.

For batch apex, if I were to do an insert on opportunities, I assume it will fire those triggers and if the same governing limit apply?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, triggers will fire when the [Batch Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) runs and if you have large numbers of records in your batch you will hit the governor limit.

One solution would be to set the batch size to 1 so that every time the triggers fire there will only be 1 record. The batch class can be started with a batch size of one using something like this:

```
Id batchInstanceId = Database.executeBatch(new MyBatchClass(), 1);
```

Another solution, and probably the best one, is to [bulkify your triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3a_Bulkify_Your_Code).

Answer (score 4):

A third solution is to consider if you don't need the trigger processing to occur, in addition to BarCotter's good suggestions, is to set a static boolean variable that your triggers could use to avoid trigger processing.

```
public static boolean isRunningBatch;
```

Set to true at the start of your execute method and then in your triggers:

```
if (!isRunningBatch) { //run trigger code }
```

This only makes sense if you don't need the trigger logic during the batch however.

Answer (score -2):

Just use system.isBatch() to stop executing any code during apex batch processing

Comment: That is not correct.

Comment: it worked for me though. while executing batch i had stopped the trigger handler. isBatch()

Returns true if a batch Apex job invoked the executing code, or false if not. It also returns true if a queueable Apex job invoked the code.